# UITabBar first item title overlapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I'm using tabbar with four tabs with title. I'm setting different color for selected and unselected tabs.  But only for the first tab, the selected and unselected colors & title are getting overlapped. Whenever I'm selecting first tab, title is getting added again and again. I have attached screenshot as well.

[image]

In storyboard

[image]

Anyhelp could be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the relevant code

Comment: I'm setting everything thorough storyboard only.

Comment: Why did you set unselecte... attribute to clear/semi-transparent? What property is it?

Comment: Its unselectedItemTintColor property for not selected tabbar.  To differentiate unselected tab from selected I'm using that.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is most likely from the color you use for `unselectedItemTintColor`, which you have set to have transparency. This color should probably be solid. Try changing it to a solid version of what you want to see, like `#EB989E`.

Also be aware that you are setting an internal property, and as such it may change or disappear in a future release of iOS.

Comment: After changing that color, and even after removing that property also its overlapping...

Comment: Then you must have set other properties that you do not show here, either for the tab bar or for the tab bar buttons.